# Как с помощью dlopen можно выяснить, есть ли данная библиотека в системе?

Tags: c

Как с помощью `dlopen` можно выяснить, есть ли данная библиотека в системе?

Пример:

```
Входные данне : libcrypt.so
Выходные : Yes или No
```

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а почему winapi?

Comment: Да, что-то уже подзабыл. Почему-то показалось, что это функция из WinAPI.

Answer (score 3):

посмотрите на образцовый пример из `man dlopen`.

примерно так:

```
### dlopentest.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void main() {
  char filename[20];

  scanf ("%s", filename);

  if (dlopen (filename, RTLD_LAZY))
    printf ("yes\n");
  else
    printf ("no\n");
}
```

собираем:

```
$ make dlopentest CFLAGS=-ldl
cc -ldl    dlopentest.c   -o dlopentest
```

проверяем:

```
$ echo libcrypt.so | ./dlopentest
yes
$ echo beliberda | ./dlopentest
no
```